# JSON Schema - Using conditional logic inside the referenced Json

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a json schema (main_schema) which refers to external references (also json schemas).
The structure is like this

```
{
    $id :main_schema.json,
    {
        $ref: first.json,
        $ref: second.json
    }
}
```

The complexity is that first.json has a field called country.
If country is US, then I need to validate US zip code format (as postcode) in second.json.
If country is not US, then I need to validate a different postcode format in second.json

I know conditional logic works inside one json file, but how to set conditional logic in one reference to set something in a second reference. Crude way would be to use multiple versions of main schema but I want to avoid it at any cost.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you cannot do that as I expect you want.

You will need to define properties at root level, and reference the properties in the schema you want.

Additionally, you can't have multiple keys in the same JSON object, so your schema there is invalid. You'd need to wrap the references inside an `allOf`.

Comment: Thanks, yes the two ref are in separate keys in actual file, I just skipped all that to describe the problem.

Can you guide me on your solution with an example or link to what you mean.

Also, what if I define a condition in main.json on country key from first.json. And based on that I set properties in second.json? In short is it possible to make a first.json property global (defined in main.json and accessible in both first and second?

Comment: I might be able to show some sort of solution like that, but I'm going to need to see actual schemas or parts of your actual schemas to make sure I fully understand what you're doing. I might have an idea of how _I would do it_, but that might be impossible with your current schemas, and that would waste both our times.